# Why is it allowed to write to / on MacOSX as normal user?

Tags: macos

Under MacOSX, I can create a file under root ("/") without having admin rights.
Anyone has a clue why they implemented it that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pure permissions thing. 
The group ownership is 'admin' and is group writeable. This is the same with other System directories like Applications.

Your user was created as an Admin user I'm sure. Check under System Preferences : Accounts and your account has the 'Allow user to administer this computer'. If you create a second user without that checked, they would not be allowed to install things in Applications or write files to /.